# How to improve the speed of getting request content via the request module

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, request, lxml

The below functions extract content from `'http://thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/form-guides/'` and append all content to a list. The function works fine, although the speed at which the content is scraped from the website is slow. This line `tree = html.fromstring(page.content)` in particular slows down the process. Is there a way I can improve on the speed of my request.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

greyhound_url = 'http://thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/form-guides/'
def get_page(url):
    """fxn take page url and return the links to the acticle(Field) we 
       want to scrape in a list.
    """
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    my_list = tree.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[2]/a/@href') # grab all link
    print('Length of all links = ', len(my_list))
    my_url = [page.url.split('/form-guides')[0] + str(s) for s in my_list]
    return my_url
def extract_data(my_url):
    """
    fxn take a list of urls and extract the needed infomation from 
    greyhound website. 
    return: a list with the extracted field
    """
    new_list = []
    try:
        for t in my_url:
            print(t)
            page_detail = requests.get(t)
            tree_1 = html.fromstring(page_detail.content)
            title = ''.join(tree_1.xpath('//div/h1[@class="title"]/text()'))
            race_number = tree_1.xpath("//tr[@id = 'tableHeader']/td[1]/text()")
            Distance = tree_1.xpath("//tr[@id = 'tableHeader']/td[3]/text()")
            TGR_Grade = tree_1.xpath("//tr[@id = 'tableHeader']/td[4]/text()")
            TGR1 = tree_1.xpath("//tbody/tr[@class='fieldsTableRow raceTipsRow']//div/span[1]/text()")
            TGR2 = tree_1.xpath("//tbody/tr[@class='fieldsTableRow raceTipsRow']//div/span[2]/text()")
            TGR3 = tree_1.xpath("//tbody/tr[@class='fieldsTableRow raceTipsRow']//div/span[3]/text()")
            TGR4 = tree_1.xpath("//tbody/tr[@class='fieldsTableRow raceTipsRow']//div/span[4]/text()")

            clean_title = title.split(' ')[0].strip()
            #clean title and extract track number
            Track = title.split(' ')[0].strip()
            #clean title and extract track date
            date = title.split('-')[1].strip()
            #clean title and extract track year
            year = pd.to_datetime('now').year 
            #convert date to pandas datetime
            race_date =  pd.to_datetime(date + ' ' + str(year)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            #extract race number
            new_rn = []
            for number in race_number:
                match = re.search(r'^(.).*?(\d+)$', number)
                new_rn.append(match.group(1) + match.group(2))
            new_list.append((race_date,Track,new_rn,Distance,TGR_Grade,TGR1,TGR2,TGR3,TGR4))
            
        return new_list
            
    except ConnectionError as e:
        print('Connection error, connect to a stronger network or reload the page')
```

Comment: Define "slow". Have you done measurements?

Comment: @mzjn thanks for your response, I discovered why the response is slow.

A request to one of the url's from the first function call takes forever. I need to add a time out to every request sent.